# Incrementing variable not working

Tags: variables, batch-file, increment

```
@echo off
FOR %%P IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO (
  IF EXIST %%P:\nul (
cls
SET /a count=%count%+1
dir /s /b %%P:\ |find /c "\" >NUMfiles.max
set /p "counter%count%"=<NUMfiles.max

del %%P:\apple.doc
del %%P:\orange.doc

dir /s /b %%P:\ |find /c "\" >NUMfiles.max
set /p "counter%count%%%P"=<NUMfiles.max
set /a "counter%%P"="counter%count%" - "counter%count%%%P"

  )
)

set /a finalcount="countera + counterb + counterc + counterd + countere +         counterf + counterg + counterh + counteri + counterj + counterk + counterl + counterm + countern + countero + counterp + counterq + counterr + counters + countert + counteru + counterv + counterw + counterx + countery + counterz"
ECHO Total Number of deleted files: %finalcount%
```

The program is scanning each and every drive to delete apple.doc & orange.doc and after finished deleted all files from all drives it will give me the total result of how many total files deleted.

Please help.

Comment: It is giving me an error "The Syntax of the Command is Incorrect"

Comment: the famous [delayed expansion trap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining All MP4s in Directory with ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/combining-all-mp4s-in-directory-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the good old `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`. When working with variables which are modified inside FOR loops, you always have to add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your script. Further you have to address your loop-modified variables with `!var!` instead of `%var%`. That should be it.

Comment: Can you help me revise my code instead to for me to fully understand because i am still having syntax error... Hope it's ok....

Comment: No need i got it working. the syntax error was coming from "" in the set command. thank you so much for this!!!